# Change paper size in sejda output?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, sejda

I'm running [sejda](http://www.sejda.org/), and I'm asking a question here on StackOverflow as that project's [support page recommends](http://www.sejda.org/development-2/support/).

I'm merging a set of PDF documents together, and output either Letter size pages for US readers, or A4 size pages for European readers.

Is there a way I can specify the page size in the XML config file or with a command-line option?

Comment: You can file a request [here](https://bitbucket.org/torakiki/sejda/issues), we like to add features solving real world issues

Comment: Thanks @torakiki, I've filed a [request](https://bitbucket.org/torakiki/sejda/issue/121/option-to-set-page-size-of-pdf-output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, the page size for the merged output PDF file is not configurable at the moment.